# How to change Label text after seconds?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have searched and tried many approaches to this problem.

With a Visual Studio 2015 WinForma app, I want a `Label`'s text to change after a time delay.

Of my many approaches, I can confirm the string value of the label has changed with a `MessageBox`, but the onscreen UI does not change.

So far I have tryed:

1: `Thread.Sleep(number)` inside `Public Form1()` before I change the value.
Result: doesn't seem to update the UI before the end of the function.

2: `nameoflabel.refresh();` EVERYWHERE.
Result: does not do anything anywhere.

3: use `System.Timers` and change the value of my `Label` inside the Timer's elapsed function.
Result: changes the value of `Label` but is not seen onscreen.

4: since everything involving a button click works perfectly to change my label text, I reseached how to imitate a button click with `buttonName.preformClick()` and made a fake button for the purpose.
Result: value changes but still nothing changes on screen.

I am starting to believe this must be a bug. Yes? No?
Anyway, here is what I need to work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public System.Timers.Timer holder;
    Label say;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        say = new Label();
        say.Text="start text";
        this.Controls.Add(say);
        holder = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        holder.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(holdone); 
        holder.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void holdone(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //messagebox is correct but onscreen gui is not
        say.Text = "new after seconds";
        MessageBox.Show(say.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: using the Timer method, you should use a reference to your `MainWindow`'s target UI element, coupled with the `Invoke` method. Since the `Elapsed` event is handled on a separate thread, you must signal the UI thread to not only change the property, but effect the property, which when cannonized by any other entity except the UI thread, `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`(non-blocking async alternate) is used.

Comment: Use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Its `Tick` event is raised in UI Thread. As of now, you should receive an `InvalidOperationException` for trying a cross-thread operation.

Comment: I have added an example based on my comment above. `Invoke` achieves the same effect that @Jimi highlights in his answer. Regardless of technique the UI must both be unblocked and be the one who effects property change for the desired live update

Comment: Updating the Text property of a control from a worker thread is not allowed.  You get an InvalidOperationException, but System.Timers.Timer is a very nasty class, it swallows all exceptions raised in the Elapsed event handler.  Use a normal timer, the one in the toolbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead, which will update the UI as you want:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer holder;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label say;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        say = new Label {AutoSize = true, Text = "start text"};
        Controls.Add(say);

        holder = new Timer {Interval = 5000};
        holder.Tick += HolderTick;
        holder.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void HolderTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        say.Text = $"new after {holder.Interval / 1000} seconds";
        holder.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution of using a form timer instead of a system timer has fixed my issue and am now using your example !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void holdone(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     say.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        say.Text = "new after seconds"; //predicated upon a declared var say = new Label()
    }); 
}
```

This is an example of a `System.Timers.Timer` `Elapsed` event handler that should (relatively) immediately affect your UI.

Comment: Thank you, this seem to be good and exceptable solution. for the moment i have used the first answer from Rufus, but will study the use of invoke and delegate for future coding. your approach seems more universal for future reference